# OpenGL unwanted triangle is appearing with texturing a square composed with 2 triangles

Tags: c++, opengl

I use SFML/OpenGl

When I'm texturing my square, (which is composed by 2 triangles), with an image, 1 unwanted triangle is appearing:

[image: link to it]

The error is the little brown triangle on the middle of the screen.

This is my code:
Drawing function:

```
glUseProgram(shader->getProgramID());

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, coordTexture);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader->getProgramID(), "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(projection));

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader->getProgramID(), "modelview"), 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(modelview));


sf::Texture::bind(&textTest, sf::Texture::Normalized);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

sf::Texture::bind(NULL);
glUseProgram(0);
```

Parameters:

```
shader = new Shader(vertexSource, fragmentSource);
float t = taille/2;
float points[] = { -t,-2.0,-t, -t,-2.0,t, t,-2.0,-t,
t,-2.0,-t, t,-2.0,t, -t,-2.0,t};

float text[] = {        
                0.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0, 1.0,0.0,
                1.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0,1.0,

                };
for (int i = 0; i < 6*3; i++)
{
    vertices[i] = points[i];
    this->couleurs[i] = 1.0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 6 * 2; i++)
{
    this->coordTexture[i] = text[i];
}
shader->charger();

textTest.loadFromFile("lama.jpg");
```

And it's strange, because when I change:

```
float text[] = {        
                0.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0, 1.0,0.0,
                1.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0,1.0,                  
                };
```

to (switch coordinates) :

```
float text[] = {        
                1.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0,1.0,
                0.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0, 1.0,0.0,

                };
```

The unwanted triangle disappear, but of course the result for the texturing is not the good.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are drawing 9 vertices = 3 triangles. Square sounds to me as if there should just be 6 vertices

Comment: Oh no you're right, Thank you. Why I didn't see that ?! I should go to bed actually.